# Sending the post method contents in REST invocation from WSO2 ESB

Tags: rest, wso2, wso2-esb

I have been trying to invoke a rest operation from my wso2 ESB and was successful in invoking the rest post method from WSO2 ESB. But, un luckily i was not able to access the data that i posted, neither through request parameters nor through request attributes.

PS: I don't want to frame a get kind of URLs for my post request.

is there a solution to this ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the correct content type so it will preserve POST request data.This [post](http://pradeepfernando.blogspot.com/2011/05/post-variables-get-dropped-while-going.html) will help you to understand the reason.

Edit.

1) Add the following entry to axis2.xml in message builders.

```
<messageBuilder contentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                    class="org.apache.synapse.commons.builders.XFormURLEncodedBuilder"/>
```

2) then access the required parameter in esb using

```
<property name="NameOfTheProperty" expression="//xformValues/NameOfTheProperty/text()"/>
```

Comment: <property action="set" name="messageType" scope="axis2"
                type="STRING" value="application/xml"/>
            <property action="set" name="ContentType" scope="axis2"
                type="STRING" value="application/xml"/>

Comment: Can you try the added instructions.

Comment: I have tried all the possible ways... i have observed the request reaching to my servlet, but when i try to access that, i see null values. Probably attributes or parameters are not getting set.